# STM32 - RTOS - Max Stack Size

Tags: stm32, rtos

I'm using STM32F103R8T6 with RTOS with 2 threads

```
osThreadDef(ManagerTask, ManagerThread, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
  ManagerTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(ManagerTask), NULL);
  osThreadDef(RFIDTask, RFIDThread, osPriorityNormal, 0, 256);
  RFIDTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(RFIDTask), NULL);
```

when i try to give the any thread a stack size of >512, neither of the tasks run, but when using 128 and 256 as the above example everything is fine.

So how to i know the max total stack size that i can allocate for my threads ?

in my RTOS Config

```
#define configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE                 ((uint16_t)128)
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE                    ((size_t)3072)
```

Comment: Do you create anything else provided by FreeRTOS like queues, mutexes or semaphores? Also, which heap implementation do you use?

Comment: I used STM32CubeMX to generate the RTOS config and TRUESTUDIO code template, i will use semaphores but not for now, the code doesn't include any queues or mutexes or semaphores

Comment: also i'm using HEAP3 for memory managment

Comment: If you use heap3 then configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE has no effect, as heap3 is a simple wrapper for malloc and free, which uses your regular heap.

Comment: so i have to switch to another heap ? if so, what do you recommend ?

Comment: sorry i'm using HEAP4

Comment: No, using heapX or heapY shouldn't have such effect. So far I have no idea what could be causing this. Have you tried stepping through the RTOS code that's responsible for creating the tasks and see if they actually complete successfully?

Comment: i tried debugging the threads, but as long as they are 2 threads it's ok, when i try to add a third thread, it never runs

Comment: i fixed the 2 threads memory issues by increasing heap size, but now a third thread never runs

Comment: No, i mean have you tried stepping inside the function that creates the first thread? Also, in case of heap4, the value of configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE does matter. Have you tried increasting it?

Comment: yes i increased it, that's why two threads with 512,128 is now working, but a third thread with same priority never runs the startTask function of that thread, i didn't try to debug RTOS kernal itself

Comment: I've just checked the implementation of `osThreadCreate` - it simply passes the struct fields further to FreeRTOS function `xTaskCreate`. In case of the stack size, those are specified as as number of *words*, not number of *bytes*. In case of your MCU, that means that the `ManagerTask` you've defined has a size of 128 words = 512 bytes. On the other hand `configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE` defines the total available RTOS heap by *bytes*.

Comment: isn't 1 word = 2bytes ?

Comment: STM32 is 32-bit. Full word is 4 bytes long, half-word is 2 bytes long.

Comment: Ok, using the heap size 5000, with 3 threads (512,256,128) = 3584, so that means using HEAP4, the 3 threads can run, right ?

Comment: Theoretically yes, it should. Assuming you don't create anything on your own (semaphores, mutexes, queues). I'm not sure how much of that memory FreeRTOS uses on its own just so that it's able to run. Also defining a new task with stack size of let's say 128 words = 512 bytes doesn't take exactly 512 bytes from the RTOS heap but actually more, as it also needs to allocate some memory for the TCB (task control block). For exact numbers, please refer to: https://www.freertos.org/FAQMem.html

Comment: Did you change linker script as well?

Comment: @P__J__ yeah , the ram is MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

Answer (score 1):

If you use **FreeRTOS** keep in the mind that **stack size value in words** not in bytes! But configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE in bytes!

In this conditions:

- TaskA 512 words = 2048b
- TaskB 128 words = 512b
- Totaly have  = 2560b

Almost 3072 :) so if you don't use other objects it will work but if you some increase stack or will use additional objects the heap will be depleted

Source: https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html